# Queue from struct type

Tags: c++, struct, queue

Ok, that is my struct:

```
struct sudurjanie {
    string stoka_ime;
    string proizvoditel;
    double cena;
    int kolichestvo;
};
```

Next I create queue:

```
queue<sudurjanie> q;
```

But when I write this:

```
cin >> q.push(sudurjanie.stoka_ime);
```

In error list write this:

> IntelliSense: a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object

Ok, when I try this:

```
cout << q.back();
```

, why write this:

> no operator `"<<"` matches these operands

?

Comment: How is that an IntelliSense error? That seems kind of odd...

Comment: You should *not* use a double for prices! (cena means price in some slavic languages).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you may have wanted to do this instead:

```
queue<sudurjanie> q;

sudurjanie item;
cin >> item.stoka_ime;

q.push(item);
```

The line `cin>>q.push(sudurjanie.stoka_ime);` doesn't make any sense.  Literally, it means:

1. Pass `sudurjanie.stoka_ime` to `q`'s `push()` method.  This will fail, because `push()` takes an argument of type `sudurjanie` while you have supplied an argument of type `string`.
2. Read from `cin` into the result of the `push()` call, which is `void`.  This will fail because it makes no sense to read into `void`.

Comment: Ok, when I try this: cout<<q.back(); , why write this: no operator "<<" matches these operands ?

Comment: Because you are trying to write an object of type `sudurjanie` to `cout`, and `cout` has no idea how it's supposed to represent this type.  You would need to overload the `operator<<()` function yourself for this to work.  Consider trying `cout << q.back().stoka_ime << endl;` instead.

Comment: Ok but I need to get all data from q?

Comment: Then either overload `operator<<()` or stream out all elements: `cout << q.back().stoka_ime << q.back().proizvoditel << ...` and so on.

Comment: @Nikolai : Maybe it's time to consider starting over with [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/636019)...

Comment: If you need general guidance programming, this is probably not the place to ask.  SO deals with specific questions, not "make my whole program work" questions, and we generally assume that you have at least a basic grasp of the programming language you are asking about.

Answer (score 3):

Your reference to `sudurjanie.stoka_ime` is invalid as you are naming a member of the *type*, not an instance of it.

Try:

```
sudurjanie tmp;
cin >> tmp.stoka_ime;
q.push(tmp);
```

This will create an instance of `sudurjanie`, named `tmp`, read the field, then push the instance onto the queue

Answer (score 0):

Read the item in first and then add the struct to the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Your queue is a queue of `sudurjanie` structs. What you are trying to push into the queue is

a) the name of your struct and not an **instance**

b) a member of the struct (a string).